# Having trouble installing PyDE in thonny

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the library `PyDE` to run a differential evolution on an equation I've made. Whenever I try to install the library in thonny, I get an error (listed below).

I'm not the most knowledgeable with `pip` or what the errors mean so if you can help out I'd really appreciate it.

The error message from thonny's pip window:

```
Collecting PyDE
  Downloading PyDE-1.0.1.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\charlie\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\charlie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jraruxxv\\PyDE\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\charlie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jraruxxv\\PyDE\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\charlie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-wu08p02b'
         cwd: C:\Users\charlie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jraruxxv\PyDE\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\charlie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jraruxxv\PyDE\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        with open('README.rst') as file:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Process returned with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer forgot to package the `README.rst` file into the `tar.gz` archive (Python package's source distribution most likely) with `setup.py` instructions, so it's failing. Download the archive manually, open `setup.py` remove the [function](https://github.com/hpparvi/PyDE/blob/7398afe4a93c52f29e32f0f9e979c4eb02306e30/setup.py#L3) reading the `README.rst` and then install manually.

```
visit https://pypi.org/project/PyDE/#files
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e1/2d1467ad0dea7340fb4d3441e9b47c23f5860b2ceb57465239073e04ae19/PyDE-1.0.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf PyDE-1.0.1.tar.gz
cd PyDE-1.0.1
# edit the setup.py to remove the open() function
pip install .
```

Alternatively, install from GitHub:

```
pip install https://github.com/hpparvi/PyDE/zipball/master
```

If you want the **exact** version, there's no branch or tag for you, but it might be [this commit](https://github.com/hpparvi/PyDE/commit/7ad56574b9dcfe6f6f668ee52978c7cfeb4b3970) judging by the date of the PyPI package release. In that case adjust the `master` to the commit hash

```
pip install https://github.com/hpparvi/PyDE/zipball/7ad56574b9dcfe6f6f668ee52978c7cfeb4b3970
```

The reason why it works when using the GitHub link is because pip will download the full repository's snapshot (zipball, which contains the `README.rst` file) instead of the broken archive from PyPI (which does not).